# Pessimistic lock in MySQL not always working on application running in multiple instances

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, concurrency, pessimistic-locking

Hello Im trying to understand an issue related to pessimistic locks when running 3 instances of my application.
The application has, among other stuffs, a spring schedule which runs every 3 hours and I need the business logic inside the function
annotated with @Scheduled to run successfully just in one of the instances.

To accomplish this, at the beginning of this function, Im trying to lock a specific indexed row in a table just like that

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
.....
LockTableEntity entity = this.em.find(LockTableEntity.class, 1L);
this.em.lock(entity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
//this.em.lock(entity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE); I have tried this as well!!
entity.setDatLock(LocalDateTime.now());
this.em.merge(entity);
.....
```

The issue Im facing is from time to time I can get a lock in one **or** two of the instances - throwing exceptions properly LockAcquisitionException and rolling back transaction - **but not always in two instances** as I expected it to happen,
so just one of those 3 should run 'til the end!

So I would like to know what Im doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding the lock process any how?

Stack:

- Spring Boot 2.5.2
- Hibernate Core 5.4.32
- Database MySQL 5.7
- MySQL connector 8.0.25

Comment: Any guidance folks?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `LockTableEntity entity = em.find(LockTableEntity.class, 1L, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);`. It's impossible to acquire the same exclusive lock multiple times. Maybe one of your transactions times out?